# Is there any variation of Poker that force each player call the blind every hand?

Tags: texas-hold-em, rules, blinds

I played poker for a while. Recently I visited my friend's home game playing hold'em forcing every player to call the blind every hand.
I'm living in a country where poker is not legist here.

Is there any variation of poker playing forced calls like this?
Thanks.

Comment: cf. [bomb pot](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=bomb+pot)

Comment: I have never seen a forced call in a game, in the90's, they were often Playing razz witha forced rasie the first round, you could not call the opener you must raise the opener

Comment: Actually, it's like an ante but instead of putting the proportional to a blind, every player puts equal to the blind then starts the betting round.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your group at a game can do anything they can all agree on. you can have a forced call or raise,even a insurance type fee to fold like half the bet or bigger antes, or more blinds, a small blind on the button is not uncommon, you can do whatever condition you want. Expermint with different things for your game. another interesting variant to betting is buying a card on the river. typically in stud and draw games, you set a price to buy a card on the river, maybe something like the price of a big blind or something that is based on the pot size. there are no federal laws that restrict this, so use your imagination. For my dime I think the best way to increase the action is to add an ante.

this is a list of things I have seen over the years to sweeten a pot,

Allow any player to straddle from any spot.
in lo-ball games they used to have a voluntary kill, where a player after recieving thier in some variations after receiving their first card cards could post a live kill before the draw, works just like any kill giving the player whom made the kill, last option to raise.

a Kill with a condition defined where the player has to post a live blind, typically after winning a pot that exceeded a certain size or has won two pots in a row.

More live blinds, three blinds under the gun, or a blind on the button.
anted, even a small ante goes a long way toward much bigger pots.

forced raise, saw this mostly in razz games, after the bring in all other players are required to raise or fold.

buying a card after the river, when a player can buy one more card, the proceeds which go into the pot, this is best suited in games where a player hold all thier own card, but with a little imagination, can be modified to suite community card games.

adding wild cards to the game.

double flops, have two flops, makes for a lot of action. one can vary this between playng for a split betwenn the hands fo the best hand of each flop, or best hand takes all.
a five hole card varation of omaha, where the best five card hand, in a players hand gets the half the pot.

Comment: Clearly answer, these bring me a clear mind to play without a doubt.
It seems I have to play differently from the standard Hold'em rule.
Yes, in my case this home-game owner wants to increase the action as you said.

Comment: There's some joke in my group that will call this all-player ante game GalaLand Hold'em.

Comment: Another strange rule is every player can add more chips during any betting round and if the player in the same spot doesn't have any money (in his bank account/his home to sell), that player has to fold. However, this rule is in the discussion. As you said, can play if all agree.

Answer (score 2):

A "blind" that must be called is not, in fact, a blind. You probably played with an ante, which is a mandatory preflop bet that is equal for all players. This does not have a separate name from hold 'em as played with blinds, it's merely a different protocol.

Comment: Yes, it's a home game setup protocol.